# left_join R dataframes, merging two columns with NAs

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

My problem is the following: Lets say I have an existing dataframe with the following columns: UID, foo, result. Result is already partially filled. A second model now predicts additional rows, generating a second dataframe containing a UID and a result column: (Code to reproduce at bottom)

```
## df_main
##    UID   foo result
##  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
## 1     1   moo    Cow
## 2     2   rum   <NA>
## 3     3  oink   <NA>
## 4     4  woof    Dog
## 5     5  hiss   <NA>

## new_prediction
##    UID result
##  <dbl>  <chr>
## 1     3    Pig
## 2     5  Snake
```

I now want to left_join the new results by UID to get the following result column:

```
## Cow
## <NA>
## Pig
## Dog
## Snake
```

But I can't get that to work, since `left_join(df_main, new_prediction, by="UID")` creates `result.x` and `result.y`. Is there any way to do this with dplyr, or alternatively, a good second step to join the columns? I looked at various functions, but finally resolved to loop over all rows manually. I am pretty certain that there is a more "R" way to do that?

Code for dataframes:

```
df_main <- tibble(UID = c(1,2,3,4,5), foo=c("moo", "rum", "oink", "woof", "hiss"), result=c("Cow", NA, NA, "Dog", NA))
new_prediction <- tibble(UID = c(3,5), result = c("Pig", "Snake"))
```

Comment: You could use `coalesce` from `dplyr` on those columns.

Comment: Do you know why R behaves that way? Why does it create a .x and .y?

Comment: @Tim, well, if you want to keep 2 different columns with the same name, it needs to modify the names to be clear where they came from.  The names of the argument of `left_join` (and `merge` before it) are `x` and `y`. so appending `".x"` or `".y"` to the duplicated column names makes it clear which original data frame they came from, based on how you called the join function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`coalesce` is your second step.

```
left_join(df_main, new_prediction, by="UID") %>%
  mutate(result = coalesce(result.x, result.y)) %>%
  select(-result.x, -result.y)
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#     UID   foo result
#   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
# 1     1   moo    Cow
# 2     2   rum   <NA>
# 3     3  oink    Pig
# 4     4  woof    Dog
# 5     5  hiss  Snake
```

`coalesce` will accept as many columns as you give it. Earlier columns have precedence in case there are multiple non-missing values.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - I knew there had to be an "R" way to do it. As a bonus, this even works with more than 2 vectors, which is great in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if this is outside the scope of this question BUT what about cases in which we have multiple sets of .x and .y columns which have non-deterministic names? i.e. we joined based on multiple columns whose names were passed in as a parameter.

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442373/903061) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gregor's answer of using `coalesce`, you could also "manually" join the columns with `ifelse`.

```
left_join(df_main, new_prediction, by = "UID") %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(is.na(result.x),result.y, result.x)) %>%
  select(-c(result.x, result.y))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# UID foo   result
# <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
# 1  1.00 moo   Cow   
# 2  2.00 rum   <NA>  
# 3  3.00 oink  Pig   
# 4  4.00 woof  Dog   
# 5  5.00 hiss  Snake
```