# Coalesce pairs of variables within a dataframe based on a regular expression

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, coalesce

I want to use `dplyr::coalesce` to find the first non-missing value between pairs of variables in a dataframe containing multiple pairs of variable. The goal is to create a new dataframe with now only one copy for each pair of variable (a coalesce variable without NA values).

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
      A_1=c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5),
      A_2=c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA),
      B_1=c(NA, NA, 13, 14, 15),
      B_2=c(11, 12, NA, NA, NA))


Expected output: 

A  B
1  11
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
```

I am guessing a mix of `dplyr::coalesce` with maybe `dplyr::mutate_at` based on regular expression could be use but I am not sure how to do it. Is there a way to complete this task with the tidyverse grammar?

Thanks!

EDIT: thanks everyone for your answers! However, I should have included the naming convention for my variables to facilitate the transfer of your answers to my actual problem.. I am sorry about that. My variables are geochemistry variables named in two parts (name of chemical element plus name of core).

Example: `Al_TAC4.25.275` where `Al` is the element and `TAC4.25.275` is the core. I want to coalesce the data from 3 different cores (second part of name) for each element (first part of name). I have 25 pairs of element to coalesce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use transmute, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  A_1 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5),
  A_2 = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA),
  B_1 = c(NA, NA, 13, 14, 15),
  B_2 = c(11, 12, NA, NA, NA)
  )

df %>%
  transmute(A = coalesce(A_1, A_2),
            B = coalesce(B_1, B_2))
#>   A  B
#> 1 1 11
#> 2 2 12
#> 3 3 13
#> 4 4 14
#> 5 5 15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Another option, if you have lots of "A_*" and "B_*" columns (source: [Romain François](https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54#issuecomment-613882658), user: [@Romain Francois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499163/romain-francois)):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  A_1 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5),
  A_2 = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA),
  B_1 = c(NA, NA, 13, 14, 15),
  B_2 = c(11, 12, NA, NA, NA)
  )

coacross <- function(...) {
  coalesce(!!!across(...))
}

df %>%
  transmute(A = coacross(starts_with("A_")),
            B = coacross(starts_with("B_")))
#>   A  B
#> 1 1 11
#> 2 2 12
#> 3 3 13
#> 4 4 14
#> 5 5 15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Based on your updated question, you don't have lots of "A_*" or "B_*" columns, but instead lots of "*_1", "*_2", and "*_3" columns. I think this is the most straightforward solution for your use-case:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Al_TAC4.25.275 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 Al_TAC4.25.276 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, NA),
                 Al_TAC4.25.277 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3),
                 Au_TAC4.25.275 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 Au_TAC4.25.276 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, NA),
                 Au_TAC4.25.277 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA),
                 Ar_TAC4.25.275 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1),
                 Ar_TAC4.25.276 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 Ar_TAC4.25.277 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3))

df
#>   Al_TAC4.25.275 Al_TAC4.25.276 Al_TAC4.25.277 Au_TAC4.25.275 Au_TAC4.25.276
#> 1              1             NA             NA              1             NA
#> 2              1             NA             NA              1             NA
#> 3              1              2              3              1              2
#> 4             NA              2             NA             NA              2
#> 5             NA              2             NA             NA              2
#> 6             NA             NA              3             NA             NA
#>   Au_TAC4.25.277 Ar_TAC4.25.275 Ar_TAC4.25.276 Ar_TAC4.25.277
#> 1             NA              1             NA             NA
#> 2             NA              1             NA             NA
#> 3              3              1              2              3
#> 4             NA             NA              2             NA
#> 5             NA             NA              2             NA
#> 6             NA              1              2              3

names(df) %>% 
  split(str_extract(., '[:alpha:]+')) %>%
  map_dfc(~ coalesce(!!!df[.x][c(1,2,3)]))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      Al    Ar    Au
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     1     1
#> 3     1     1     1
#> 4     2     2     2
#> 5     2     2     2
#> 6     3     1    NA

# change the order of the list to change the 'priority'
names(df) %>% 
  split(str_extract(., '[:alpha:]+')) %>%
  map_dfc(~ coalesce(!!!df[.x][c(3,2,1)]))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      Al    Ar    Au
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     1     1
#> 3     3     3     3
#> 4     2     2     2
#> 5     2     2     2
#> 6     3     3    NA

names(df) %>% 
  split(str_extract(., '[:alpha:]+')) %>%
  map_dfc(~ coalesce(!!!df[.x][c(2,1,3)]))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      Al    Ar    Au
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     1     1
#> 3     2     2     2
#> 4     2     2     2
#> 5     2     2     2
#> 6     3     2    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You could: `df %>% 
  transmute(across(ends_with("_1"), 
                ~coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), '1$', '2'))), 
                .names = "{.col}_coalesce")) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(ends_with('coalesce')), ~ str_remove(., "\\_1"))` to avoid the function?! or to avoid `coalesce` twice.

Comment: Yeah! I tried this approach but couldn't figure out the fine details - thanks @TarJae! I think it would be worth adding that to your answer :)

Comment: This works wonderfully thanks :) But if I may ask for some more clarification with respect to my problem:  I have about 25 pairs or variable (actually, each 25 variables is repeated 3 times; example: there are variables `A_1`, `A_2`, `A_3`...`Z_1`, `Z_2`, `Z_3` and I want to coalesce to `A`,... `Z` as to reduce the number of variable. Is there a way to generalize your code to avoid specifying `A = ...`, `B = ....` ? Secondly, is there a way to built in a priority in selecting the variable to infill the coalesce variable? For example if I want in priority to have `_2` over `_1` as infill?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a potential solution @AntoineLachance

Answer (score 8):

Here is another more concise solution, comparing to my other one. I think the use of `cur_data()` function is very helpful but you could also use `across(everything())` in its place:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

unique(sub("(\\D)_\\d+", "\\1", names(df))) %>%
  map_dfc(~ df %>%
            select(starts_with(.x)) %>%
             summarise(!!.x := do.call(coalesce, cur_data())))

  A  B
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
```

Here is another solution for as many pairs as possible. Just note that I used `bang bang` operator (`!!!`) in order to collapse elements of a data frame into standalone single arguments so that I could apply `coalesce` on them:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df, sub("(\\D)_\\d+", "\\1", names(df))), function(x) {
  coalesce(!!!x)
})))

  A  B
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
```

Comment: Fell very happy to see you here!

Comment: It is always my pleasure brother :)

Answer (score 5):

A base R option

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    split.default(df, gsub("_.*", "", names(df))),
    rowSums,
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
)
```

gives

```
  A  B
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
```

Comment: base R brothers! you know I am enamored by `igraph` and network analysis. It totally changed my perspective on how I look at things :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Good to hear that. Enjoy your `igraph` trip :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative with pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything()
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name = substr(name, 1, 1)) %>% 
  na.omit %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value,
    values_fn = list
  ) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(A, B))
```

```
      A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    11
2     2    12
3     3    13
4     4    14
5     5    15
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I believe this solution continues to work even after your edit. It works regardless of the number of elements or the number of cores per element. You just need to make sure things are named consistently, in the form `"{element}_{core}"`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(variable = str_extract(name, "^[^_]+")) %>% 
  group_by(id, variable) %>% 
  # Arrange by name (e.g. A_1) so that we could select the first non-NA
  arrange(name) %>% 
  summarise(value = value[1]) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "variable")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id     A     B
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    11
2     2     2    12
3     3     3    13
4     4     4    14
5     5     5    15
```

Answer (score 2):

I have asked for it here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6109 where there are some possible solutions. For example

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    transmute(map2_dfc(.x = across(ends_with("_1"), .names = '{sub("_1","",.col)}'), 
                    .y = across(ends_with("_2")), 
                    .f = coalesce))
  A  B
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
```

Or also using the function

```r
coalesce_prefix <- function(prefix) {
  exprs <- map(prefix, function(p) {
    expr(coalesce(
      !!sym(paste0(p, ".x")),
      !!sym(paste0(p, ".y"))
    ))
  })
  names(exprs) <- prefix
  exprs
}
```